# Sequential' object has no attribute 'output_names' while saving keras model

Tags: python, keras

I am using Keras to load mnist data and traing, while saving the keras data. I am getting following error. complete code is here....

```
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential()
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Flatten())
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation=tf.nn.relu))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation=tf.nn.relu))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation=tf.nn.softmax))
```

### --------------------------------------------

```
 KERAS_MODEL_NAME = 'keras.hdf5'

tf.keras.models.save_model(model, KERAS_MODEL_NAME)
new_model=tf.keras.models.load_model(KERAS_MODEL_NAME)
predictions = new_model.predict([x_test])


getting following error 

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-be5d5fd55018> in <module>
     29 #tf.keras.models.save_model(model, KERAS_MODEL_NAME)
     30 tf.keras.models.save_model(model, KERAS_MODEL_NAME)
---> 31 new_model=tf.keras.models.load_model(KERAS_MODEL_NAME)
     32 predictions = new_model.predict([x_test])

AttributeError: 'Sequential' object has no attribute 'output_names'
```

I also tried to all option given [here](https://jovianlin.io/saving-loading-keras-models/) but didnt worked here..

Comment: @sdcbr no I tried all option given there, but none worked for me.https://jovianlin.io/saving-loading-keras-models/

Comment: Alright, I removed my comment!

Comment: @sdcbr could you please vote it so that it dont get into spam.